# How to match string in nested JSON using Switch node

Tags: javascript, node-red

Using Node-RED I receive this msg.payload (already) JSONified:

```
{ "name": "LightOnIntent", "slots": { "light": { "name": "light", "value": "kitchen" } } }
```

In my flow's first switch node I successfully match against `msg.payload.name`. The second switch should work with the contents of the slots, e.g. continue via 1 if `msg.payload.slots` contains "light".

I can't get it to work with a plain switch node. Even with specific array addressing, looking for "light" in `msg.payload.slots[0]` doesn't work. Do I need a function node to look for elements within the nested element?

Comment: In a function node I would approach it with `if ( "light" in msg.payload.slots ){ ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse your json into object using `JSON.parse()`.Then in your object `slots.light` is an object with keys `name` and `value`.Access key's values using `object['key']` or `object.key`

```
msg.payload.slots['light'].name;//matches against light
msg.payload.slots['light'].value;//matches against kitchen
```

**Equivalent to**

```
msg.payload.slots.light.name;//matches against light
msg.payload.slots.light.value;//matches against kitchen
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to get the element and its contents in a function. The question is if I can use **Node-RED**'s Switch node to find out if a nested object contains a value.